# Cant remove admob from scrollview

Tags: java, android, scrollview, admob

Ive got this project and ive put admob on it but the ad must always be on the bottom of the screen and when you scroll up and down the page the ad must stay in the same place.

It seems ive done something wrong somewhere as the ad has its own little scroll view layout? Ive put a screen shot below along with the code for the layout

**edited homexml code but with error**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/ScrlView"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:layout_weight="1">

      <ScrollView
          android:id="@+id/ScrlView"
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height="fill_parent"
          android:layout_above="@+id/MainActivity"
          android:layout_marginBottom="20dp" >

  <LinearLayout
      android:id="@+id/layoutForScroll"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="100dp"
      android:orientation="vertical" >


     <TextView
         android:id="@+id/header"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_marginTop="23dp"
         android:gravity="center"
         android:text="Welcome To Ride Count!"
         android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
         android:textColor="#1E90FF"
         android:textStyle="bold" >
</TextView>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/layoutTextViews_one"
            android:layout_width="280dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:background="@drawable/smallbox1" >

     <TextView
         android:id="@+id/txtCountLabel_one"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
         android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
         android:gravity="center"
         android:text="Rides Ridden:"
         android:textColor="#1E90FF"
         android:textStyle="bold" >
</TextView>

    <TextView android:textStyle="bold" android:gravity="center" android:text="0000" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_width="match_parent" android:id="@+id/sum"
       android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:textColor="#000000"  android:layout_marginTop="45dp"></TextView>

   </RelativeLayout>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtFact"
            android:layout_width="280dp"
            android:layout_height="180dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginTop="23dp"
            android:background="@drawable/factbox"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Tap For Fact"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

   </LinearLayout>




 </ScrollView>




     <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/MainActivity"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="2">
    </LinearLayout>

    <com.google.ads.AdView
        xmlns:googleads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"
        android:id="@+id/ad"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        googleads:adSize="SMART_BANNER"
        googleads:adUnitId="@string/admob_id" />

</LinearLayout>
```

[image]

ad mob layout code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/ad_catalog_layout"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
    <TextView android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/banner_bottom" />
    <TextView android:id="@+id/status"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0px"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="" />

    <com.google.ads.AdView
        xmlns:googleads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"
        android:id="@+id/ad"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        googleads:adSize="IAB_MRECT"
        googleads:adUnitId="@string/admob_id" />

</LinearLayout>
```

home XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/backgroundtowers"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:scrollbars="vertical"
    android:weightSum="1" >

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/ScrlView"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_above="@+id/MainActivity"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/layoutForScroll"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/header"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="23dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="Welcome To Ride Count"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                android:textColor="#1E90FF"
                android:textStyle="bold" >
            </TextView>

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/layoutTextViews_one"
                android:layout_width="280dp"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:background="@drawable/smallbox1" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/txtCountLabel_one"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="Rides Ridden:"
                    android:textColor="#1E90FF"
                    android:textStyle="bold" >
                </TextView>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/sum"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="45dp"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="0000"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                    android:textColor="#000000"
                    android:textStyle="bold" >
                </TextView>
            </RelativeLayout>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txtFact"
                android:layout_width="280dp"
                android:layout_height="180dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginTop="23dp"
                android:background="@drawable/factbox"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="Tap For Fact"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textStyle="bold" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/MainActivity"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="0dp" >
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: When you say "the ad has its own little scroll view layout," can you explain that or provide a screenshot of the issue?

Comment: theres a screenshot of it above if you look at the ad part it has a little line showing its using a scrollview layout thing

Comment: Ahh, I see that now. Can you post the code of how you create the ad?

Comment: added the layout code for the admod thing

Comment: What are the title and status `TextView`s for?

Comment: thats for some homepage features ive got on my app

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the `layout_height` and `layout_width` to `wrap_content` of your ad to see if that removes it. You may also want to try using the `SMART_BANNER` option in `asSize` to adjust for size automatically.

The `SMART_BANNER` option was added in AdMob version 6.0. Take a look at https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/admob/smart-banners. It's way easier to work with.

```
<com.google.ads.AdView
    xmlns:googleads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"
    android:id="@+id/ad"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    googleads:adSize="SMART_BANNER"
    googleads:adUnitId="@string/admob_id" />
```

I'd use a `LinearLayout` since it's a bit easier in this case, but you can still use a `RelativeLayout` if you prefer them. The idea is to put the `AdView` in the XML and use `layout_weight` to the rest of your layout to fill the View.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/ScrlView"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:layout_weight="1">
       <!-- ... -->
    </ScrollView>

    <com.google.ads.AdView
        xmlns:googleads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"
        android:id="@+id/ad"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        googleads:adSize="SMART_BANNER"
        googleads:adUnitId="@string/admob_id" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: ok ive set both of the things to wrap_content and it still does the scroll view thing whats this all about? This new code

Comment: The code is just trying to replace your current `com.google.ads.AdView` XML with a SMART_BANNER

Comment: ok ive just done that and the wrap content stuff but its still making the scroll view thing? Someone said another answer below but it doesnt make any sense to me but it might to you...

Comment: The solution from Bill is the correct solution in the long run. Basically you should put the `AdView` into your _home XML_ to display at the bottom. This should alleviate the scrolling issue

Comment: ok i copy and pasted that section of code that you did above just above these last few bits of code and it still makes a scroll view layout </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>

Comment: I've added a version using `layout_weight` and `LinearLayout`.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/27337/discussion-between-james-and-kirk)

Comment: ok right ive had a look at what youve done and i might have done something wrong which has caused me to get a error so ive copied and pasted my edited code to the top of this page if you can take a look?

Comment: You have a `ScrollView` inside a `ScrollView`. Looks like you've pasted some code inside your code. The `AdView` shouldn't be in a `ScrollView`

Comment: ok ive taken that out and I think ive just killed everything :( could you change the code in the original description? sorry to sound like a idiot

Answer (score 0):

ScrollView and your AdView need to be peers in your RelativeLayout.  I have implemented exactly what you desire in this way.

```
RelativeLayout
    ScrollView
        LinearLayout
    AdView
```

Comment: could you edit the code above cause i dont really understand :/ sorry